# Spark/ Scala- Select Columns Conditionally From Dataframe

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have two hive tables `A` and `B` and their respective data frames `df_a` and `df_b`

```
A
+----+----- +-----------+
| id | name | mobile1   |
+----+----- +-----------+
| 1  | Matt | 123456798 |
+----+----- +-----------+
| 2  | John | 123456798 |
+----+----- +-----------+
| 3  | Lena |           |
+----+----- +-----------+

B
+----+----- +-----------+
| id | name | mobile2   |
+----+----- +-----------+
| 3  | Lena | 123456798 |
+----+----- +-----------+
```

And want to perform an operation similar to

```
select A.name, nvl(nvl(A.mobile1, B.mobile2), 0) from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id
```

So far I've come up with

```
df_a.join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer").select(?)
```

I can't figure out how to conditionally select either `mobile1` or `mobile2` or `0` like I did in the Hive query.

Could someone please help me with this? I'm using Spark 1.5.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @mtoto It's not the exact query I've written, but I'm trying to check if table A (df_a) does not have the moile no, then it should be taken from table B (df_b). If still not found, then give 0 as the mobile no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df_a.join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer").select(
     coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0))
)
```

If will use mobile1 if it's present, if not - then mobile2, if mobile2 is not present then 0

Comment: I get this error  

`not found: value coalesce`.  

The spark version I'm using is 1.5.0 and scala is 2.10.4. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Thanks. The error message went away. For some reason, the Ctrl+Shift+O combo didn't work for auto import in my IDE.

Comment: I had another question too- In the `select` function, I wanted to select all columns of table `A` in a particular order (the real table has a LOT of columns). I have the column names and order in a string, e.g., "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address". I wanted to select it all like  

`df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer").select(
     "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address",
     coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0))
)`. Could something like this be accomplished?

Comment: @Amber Use `df_a.columns.filter(here filter names): _*                                                    `

Comment: Using `*` wouldn't ensure I get the columns in the order that I needed :(  The order that I need is different from the actual order in the table, e.g., The table has order `id, name, address` but I need `name, id, address`. I saw that I can't use a string along with columns in the `select` function. I could use `select(df_a("name"), df_a("id"), df_a("address"))` but I was hoping there would be a simpler way because this way I'd have to mention over a hundred column names

Comment: @Amber still you can use `selectExpr`, in which you can use String with field names

Comment: `selectExpr` doesn't allow string as well as column as args. I'll ask another question for this issue and accept your answer for this question.

Comment: @Amber Thanks! :)

Comment: I added another question. Could you help me out with this as well?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765677/spark-scala-select-columns-from-multiple-dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark sql's [nanvl](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#nanvl(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function. 
After applying it should be similar to:

```
df_a.join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.select(df_a("name"), nanvl(nanvl(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2")), 0))
```

Comment: The link you provided says  

`Returns col1 if it is not NaN, or col2 if col1 is NaN`  

NaN means Not a Number, right?  

I wanted the condition to work if no value is present in the table column