# Spark/ Scala- Select Columns From Multiple Dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two sample dataframes `df_a` and `df_b`

```
df_a
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| id | name | mobile1   | address   |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | Matt | 123456798 |           |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | John | 123456798 |           |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | Lena |           |           |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+

df_b 
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+
| id | name | mobile2   | city  | country |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+
| 3  | Lena | 123456798 |Detroit|  USA    |
+----+------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

and I'm trying to select certain columns from both as follows

```
df_a.join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer").select(
 df_a("name"), df_a("id"), df_a("address"),
 coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0))
)
```

I want to do a similar operation on two actual dataframes where `df_a` has a huge number of columns. I want to select all the columns in `df_a` in a particular order and two columns from `df_b`. So I tried the following

```
val df_a_cols : String = "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address"
df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.select(
 df_a_cols,
 coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0))
)
```

and

```
val df_a_cols : String = "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address"
df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b, df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.selectExpr(
 df_a_cols,
 coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0))
)
```

But apparently I'm providing the wrong type of arguments for `select` and `selectExpr`

Could someone please help me with this? I'm using Spark 1.5.0.

**Update**

I tried the following

```
val df_a_cols : String = "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address"
df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b.as("DFB"), df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.select(
 df_a_cols+",coalesce(DFA.mobile1, DFB.mobile2, 0)"
)
```

and got an error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address,coalesce(DFA.mobile1, DFB.mobile2, 0) ' given input columns id, name, mobile1, address, mobile2, city, country;
```

Then I tried

```
val df_a_cols : String = "name,id,address"
df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b.as("DFB"), df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.select(
 df_a_cols+",coalesce(mobile1, mobile2, 0)"
)
```

And got

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve ' name,id,address,coalesce(mobile1, mobile2, 0) ' given input columns id, name, mobile1, address, mobile2, city, country;
```

With

```
val df_a_cols : String = "name,id,address"
df_a.as("DFA").join(df_b.as("DFB"), df_a("id") <=> df_b("id"), "left_outer")
.selectExpr(
 df_a_cols+",coalesce(mobile1, mobile2, 0)"
)
```

I got

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.10] failure: identifier expected

name,id,address,coalesce(mobile1, mobile2, 0)
    ^
```

Comment: `select($"*", coalesce(df_a("mobile1"), df_b("mobile2"), lit(0)))`

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for correcting me - I didn't have possibility to check it, I don't know why I thought that it is possible :O

Comment: @T.Gawęda Yeah, I am pretty sure I've tried this once or twice myself. If you want to answer this feel free to post `$"*"` version.

Comment: @zero323 $"*" won't ensure the order of columns I need. I'll see if I can find a way to do that.  

Is there a way to use `val df_a_cols : String = "DFA.name,DFA.id,DFA.address"` with `$`? Like $df_a_cols

Comment: Hi @Amber, I know this is an old thread but did you find a solution?

Comment: @riyaB No Riya, I wasn't able to find any solution